# How to kill a NOHUP process launched via SSH

Tags: nohup

I started a rar archiving of a huge folder, forgetting to split in multiple rar archives.
How can I stop the process?

Comment: Use `ps ax` to find the process. Use `kill` to kill it. See `man kill`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in again, use [ps -a](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) to find the relevant process IDs, then kill it with [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill).

Comment: Whoever gave the -1 to this question was wrong. I made extensive research. I found many options but none of the scenarios discussed were not applicable to mine. Thanks Paul!

Comment: I suspect the down-vote is because the question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not a programming question. It should probably be migrated to http://superuser.com.